# Abrir archivo desde otra ubicacion mediante ruta relativa

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Necesito abrir un archivo que se encuentra en otro directorio del que se está trabajando, intenté con:

```
open("../carpeta/subcarpeta1/subcarpeta2/archivo.log")
```

pero cuando corro el script obtengo:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'carpeta/subcarpeta1/subcarpeta2/archivo.log'

El código completo es:

```
!/usr/local/bin/python3.5

import sendMail
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import *
from subprocess import call
import sys
import subprocess
import os.path
import unittest
from importlib import util

os.getcwd()
result = open("../ISV1/testing/log/testResult.log")
print (result)
```

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente:

```
code
├── ISV1
│ ├── testing (acá tengo los scripts de los test)
│     ├── log 
│          └── archivo1.py (archivo que quiero leer)
│── server-test
│ └── script.py
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Puse las barras invertidas como me recomendaron, y nada.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé, lo estás haciendo bien. Quizá si pegas el código veamos el fallo en otro lugar.

Comment: Yamila sería de gran ayuda que proporcionaras la estructura de tu proyecto. Estás usando una **ruta relativa a la localización de tu script principal**. ¿Estás usando la ruta en un módulo importado?

Comment: Editado con la estructura y el código que uso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo, debes usar la barra diagonal como separador. Los sistemas UNIX utilizan una barra diagonal (`/`) a diferencia de Windows que utiliza una barra invertida (`\`) como separador de rutas. En caso contrario se toma como secuencias de escape, lo que causa que, por ejemplo, en `\log\testResult.log` `\t` sea una tabulación.

Por otro lado, partiendo de la siguiente estructura (que es lo que pareces tener tu proyecto) y suponiendo que tu script principal (el que ejecutas) es `script.py` (situado dentro de `test-server`):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes posicionarte en el directorio padre que contiene tanto a `ISV1` y `test-server`. Para ello simplemente usa la sintaxis (dot dot):

```
result = open("../ISV1/testing/log/testResult.log")
```

Answer (score 0):

He probado a abrir un archivo tal y como comentas. Lo primero que deberías hacer es asignar el archivo abierto a una variable:

```
archivo = open("carpeta/subcarpeta1/subcarpeta2/archivo.log")
```

Y prueba a cambiar en el directorio las `\` por `/`.

Esto debería solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Probado pero no funciona